# iOS App Size - [ Configuration / Resources Local Data / Cloud ]

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, size

I have recently started working in iOS Development, I have noticed the app size kept on increasing as the project proceeds. There's a risk of crossing threshold of 150MB within couple of months, Apple then restricts downloading the app from Mobile Data. It will reduce the consumer base and discourage users to download it.

Does anyone have suggestions / tips how to control it.

Comment: Use JPEGs or other compressible formats for images instead of PNGs (which means no alpha channel transparency), lower the bitrates for any movie files, use mp3's over wav's or caf's, etc etc... Code does some increases in file size, but the big hitters are the media accompanying the app bundle.

Comment: If you are stuck using PNGs, you can run them through OptiPNG to cut the size down a bit.

Comment: Look at the big files and remove them. PNGs are automatically recompressed with (Apple-modified) pngcrush so there's not much you can do to help there. You can use `pngcrush -rem all` to remove unnecessary chunks, especially if you use Fireworks (note that they'll no longer be editable in Fireworks) — this removes gamma and DPI information, but those are ignored on iPhone anyway.

Comment: @SLaks The `/* */` optimization operator is more effective.

Comment: Okay, what does your app do? Which files are taking up the most space? I'm guessing it's video / images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reconfigure some of your code to be more efficient.  reduce duplicated code.  i'm not sure how much effect white space has on the app size.

Comment: whitespace shouldn't matter with compiled code

Comment: whitespace _won't_ matter with compiled code.
There's no assembly for two line returns or a tab-space..

Answer (score 1):

Remove code

Remove images

Comment: Remove video. Remove features. +1